# Unable to get XML response for GET request

Tags: xml, rest, jersey, jax-rs, httprequest

I am trying to implement GET request using JAX-RS to retrieve messages as per the [javabrains tutorial](https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs/lessons/Returning-Xml-Response/).

I have included the @XmlRootElement in the model class. Even then, I get the 500 internal server error, and I don't see any error message in the console.

I get the output for GET request on the browser if I use MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, but not when I use MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.

[This is the link to the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRPgc.jpg)

Below are the classes:

```
package org.dhivyaudayakumar.itmd566.dhivya.resources;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.dhivyaudayakumar.itmd566.dhivya.model.Message;
import org.dhivyaudayakumar.itmd566.dhivya.service.MessageService;

@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {

    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messageService.getAllMessages();
    }
}
```

```
package org.dhivyaudayakumar.itmd566.dhivya.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.dhivyaudayakumar.itmd566.dhivya.model.Message;

public class MessageService {

    public List<Message> getAllMessages(){
        Message m1 = new Message(1L, "This is the first message", "Dhivya");
        Message m2 = new Message(2L, "This is the second message", "Dhivya");

        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        messageList.add(m1);
        messageList.add(m2);

        return messageList;
    }
}
```

```
package org.dhivyaudayakumar.itmd566.dhivya.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Message {

    public long id;
    public String message;
    public Date created;
    public String author;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(long id, String message, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
        this.created = new Date();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

I have the following dependencies in pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Below dependency for JSON support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

As per the tutorial, there was no need to include any dependency for xml output, but I searched the internet and added jaxb dependency, but that didn't help solve the issue.
Can anyone please help me figure this?

Comment: Have you checked whether your controller is getting invoked or not. Try Logging or printing something inside controller for now and see till where your flow is working

Comment: And if you are getting some kind of error then provide full stack trace for it.